# Unit test for custom redirect using react/testing-library

Tags: react-testing-library

I am very new to React. have a component like so:

```js
const MyRedirect = () => <Redirect from='/something' to='/somethingelse' />
```

Now I want to write tests for it. Can anyone give me inputs?

Comment: Could you provide the content of your `Redirect` component ?

Comment: I worked it out. Added a custom router component to the test mocking my actual routes and redirects. Then I used history.push('/something') and checked that it pushed to '/somethingelse'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out. Added a custom router component to the test mocking my actual routes and redirects. Then I used history.push('/something') and checked that it pushed to '/somethingelse'.